# async.js map function picking wrong overload?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to fetch a bunch of parameters out of [AWS SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html#getParameter-property) and wanted to use [async.js Map](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#map) to do it. To get a single parameter, I need to use code (typescript) that looks like this

```js
import { default as SSM } from 'aws-sdk/clients/ssm';

const ssm: SSM = new SSM({region: 'us-west-2'});
ssm.getParameter({Name: 'foo'}, (err, data) => console.log(data));
```

To avoid callback hell, I found `async.js`, and ended up doing something like this:

```js
import { default as SSM } from 'aws-sdk/clients/ssm';
import { series } from 'async';

series([
  (f) => { ssm.getParameter({Name: 'foo'}, (err, data) => { f(err, data.Parameter?.Value)}) },
  (f) => { ssm.getParameter({Name: 'bar'}, (err, data) => { f(err, data.Parameter?.Value)}) },
  (f) => { ssm.getParameter({Name: 'baz'}, (err, data) => { f(err, data.Parameter?.Value)}) },
], (err, result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Which *does* work, but it's kinda ugly. In looking more at the `async.js` docs, I came across [`map()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#map) and thought it sounded like a better replacement. I tried writing code like this:

```js
const params = [{Name: 'foo'},
                {Name: 'bar'}, 
                {Name: 'baz'}];
map(params, ssm.getParameter, (err: any, data: any) => console.log(data));
```

but I can't even get it to compile. I'm getting this error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/tester.ts:15:5 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ Name: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(((err: AWSError, data: GetParameterResult) => void) | undefined)[] | IterableIterator<((err: AWSError, data: GetParameterResult) => void) | undefined> | Dictionary<...>'.
  Type '{ Name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '(((err: AWSError, data: GetParameterResult) => void) | undefined)[]'.
    Type '{ Name: string; }' is not assignable to type '(err: AWSError, data: GetParameterResult) => void'.
      Type '{ Name: string; }' provides no match for the signature '(err: AWSError, data: GetParameterResult): void'.

15 map(params, ssm.getParameter, (err: any, data: any) => console.log(data));
       ~~~~~~

    at createTSError (x/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:421:12)
    at reportTSError (x/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:425:19)
    at getOutput (x/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:553:36)
    at Object.compile (x/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:758:32)
    at Module.m._compile (x/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:837:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (x/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:840:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

I'm not even sure what to make of that error. Seems like it's trying to marry my call up with an overload of `map()` that's different? Appreciate any help.

Would also love to hear of other approaches re: SSM and getting large amounts of configuration data using the Javascript AWS SDK if someone has better alternatives.

Comment: Seems to be a bug with aws-sdk typing. Probably the same as reported here? https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3059

Comment: I think you're right! Thanks much for the tip. I'd accept that answer and update if/when the bug gets fixed if you'd like.